# how to declare static variable

Tags: iphone, uilabel

when i creating 
static int variable;
is giving error like expected specifier qualifier

Comment: Please give more detail, including surrounding code snippet. Here's a guess though: Objective-C doesn't have a notion of static members of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a lot to go on, but something I tripped over in one of my projects is that static variables can only be declared in the `@implementation` section of a .m file.  If you declare a static variable in the `@interface` section it throws a compiler error.